# MemberQ[{0.01, 0.05}, (0.01*9*2)/9/2] returns False

Tags: machine-precision

Multiplying and dividing by the same stuff seems to alter the value. Quite curiously, if the value you start from is large enough (greater than 0.05 in my case) you do not see the problem. Any idea why?

- `MemberQ[{0.01, 0.05}, (0.05*9*2)/9/2]` returns `True`
- `MemberQ[{0.01, 0.05}, (0.01*9*2)/9/2]` returns `False`

I can fix this using chop, but sounds like a stupid way of doing it

- `MemberQ[Chop[{0.01, 0.05} - (0.05*9*2)/9/2], 0]` returns `True`
- `MemberQ[Chop[{0.01, 0.05} - (0.01*9*2)/9/2], 0]` returns `True`

Any ideas for a better way?

Comment: Never ever compare floating point numbers without a tolerance...

Comment: Use rational numbers if you want exact comparisons, i.e., `MemberQ[Rationalize[{0.01, 0.05}], Rationalize[(0.01*9*2)/9/2]]`

Comment: To elaborate on Henrik's comment, `==` and even `===` (!) use a tolerance in Mathematica. But functions like `MemberQ`, `Union`, etc. do not, at least not for machine precision numbers. I haven't tried with arbitrary precision ones.

Comment: `MemberQ` uses `MatchQ` rather than `Equal` or `SameQ`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to `MemberQ`, the function `ContainsAny` has an option `SameTest` which can be adjusted. For your problem, the option value `Equal` is sufficient:

```
ContainsAny[{0.01, 0.05}, {(0.05*9*2)/9./2.}, SameTest -> Equal]
ContainsAny[{0.01, 0.05}, {(0.01*9*2)/9./2.}, SameTest -> Equal]

(* True *)
(* True *)
```

If you want to compare with respect to a certain tolerance, you can specify your own comparison function, e.g., as follows:

```
tol = 1. 10^-20;
myequal = {x, y} \[Function] Abs[x - y] < tol;
ContainsAny[list, {x}, SameTest -> myequal]
ContainsAny[list, {y}, SameTest -> myequal]

(* False *)
(* False *)
```

Here an example, where the actual value of the tolerance matters:

```
tol = 2. 10^-18;
myequal = {x, y} \[Function] Abs[x - y] < tol;
ContainsAny[list, {x}, SameTest -> myequal]
ContainsAny[list, {y}, SameTest -> myequal]

(* True *)
(* False *)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is all due to `MatchQ`, which is what `MemberQ` uses for making its test. With machine floats:

```
Table[{i, MatchQ[(i*9*2)/9/2, i]}, {i, .01, .1, .01}] // TableForm
```

[image: machine]

But with Mathematica arbitrary precision numbers, even at low precision

```
 Table[
   {N[i], With[{j = N[i, 2]}, MatchQ[(j*9*2)/9/2, j]]}, 
   {i, Range[10]/100}] // TableForm
```

[image: arbitrary]

we get the expected result and

```
MemberQ[{0.01`2, 0.05`2}, (0.01`2*9*2)/9/2]
```

> `True`

works.